# Generate curve from equation

Tags: modeling, mathematics

I've been trying to design a dynamic sculpture which I can only define with exactitude through mathematical equations. Now, the equations yield only lines, like you can see in the animation below: [image: Hexar monument]

I want to use these blue lines as extrusion paths in blender. How can I do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The *Add 3D Function Surface* addon allows you to do exactly this. You can download this addon [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_3d_Function_Surface). It also comes included in the built-in *Extra Objects* addon.

Once you have the addon installed, when you go to add a new mesh, you will have two additional options: 'Z function surface' and 'XYZ function surface'. If you select either of these, you will then be able to add parametric equations in the Toolbar menu to define your shape.

**Example XYZ Function Surface:**

[image]

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! It would be nice though if documentation available. Please mention in your answer that this addon is included in the "Add Mesh > Extra Objects" addon.

Comment: I found that this method yields not a curve but a mesh, however a mesh can be converted to a curve. Try pressing alt+c for a menu.

Comment: Can one do this with a quadric equation as well?  ie. `Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy + Exz + Fyz + Gx + Hy + Iz + J = 0` with bounds `x=[0,1]`, `y=[0,1]`, `z=[0,1]`.  Is there currently a way to render this in Blender with only those 16 parameters (10 from the quadric and 6 for bounds: x_lo, x_hi, y_lo, y_hi, z_lo, z_hi)?

Answer (score 14):

At some point the geometry will get converted into discrete coordinates - it's something we have to accept.

Perhaps a method as simple as generating a profile 'edge' mesh from 20 points on a curve ( blender has curve interpolation functions in python `mathutils.geometry` to get neat segments)  and then use the Screw modifier to Lathe them around

[image]