# How to create a 3D object from a specific equation

Tags: python, mesh, mathematics

I realize this has been asked before, so I apologize for the "repeat". I saw [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/607/generate-curve-from-equation/609) answer, and it mostly solved my issue. However, I can't figure out how to generate my specific equation. This is my equation:

[image]

This works from the range -1 <= x <= 1. For the really big equation, the "x" should actually be z, and the "h" should be x (I had to use those to graph it on Desmos). In any case, I tried inputting the first half of the equation with the Blender Add Mesh: Extra Objects > Math Function > Z Math Surface by typing this:

```
(sqrt(-16*fabs(x)+40*sqrt(fabs(x))*y-16*pow(x,2)-25*pow(y,2)+16)+15*x)/15
```

The result is an error evaluating the expression. Do I have to set the range somehow? Would it be better to use XYZ Math Surface? (and if so, how?). Or am I just doing something wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Lee. Not sure what you mean by 'two asterisks each'. Can you edit the question and put 4 spaces before the line with the code. This will disable the formatting so that you can enter it as-is.

Comment: @RichSedman, Got it. I didn't know about adding four spaces. Thanks for the tip, the proper change has been made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @TLousky quite rightly points out, the problem is due to the evaluation of the equation throwing an exception due to the sqrt(...) function attempting to find the square root of a negative number (which doesn't have a 'real' answer).

To avoid the Z Equation from hitting this problem you can use a *conditional* assignment.

In Python you can assign a variable based on whether a certain condition is met as follows :

```
myvar = <value> if <condition> else <othervalue>
```

Where *value* is the value to assign if the *condition* is True and *othervalue* is the value to assign if the *condition* is False. The same style of conditional assignment can be used in Blender for the Z Equation.

In your example, the failure occurs because the contents of the initial sqrt(...) function evaluates below zero, so the condition to identify 'valid' values should be :

```
(-16*fabs(x)+40 * sqrt(fabs(x)) * y - 16 * pow(x,2) - 25 * pow(y,2) + 16)>=0.0
```

The value to assign if this condition is *True* would be :

```
( sqrt(-16*fabs(x)+40 * sqrt(fabs(x)) * y - 16 * pow(x,2) - 25 * pow(y,2) + 16)  + 15 * x)/15
```

And the value to assign if the condition is *False* would be :

```
(0 + 15 * x)/15
```

(ie, for values < 0 assume that sqrt(...) is zero)

Putting this all together, the Z Equation should be :

```
( sqrt(-16*fabs(x)+40 * sqrt(fabs(x)) * y - 16 * pow(x,2) - 25 * pow(y,2) + 16)  + 15 * x)/15 if (-16*fabs(x)+40 * sqrt(fabs(x)) * y - 16 * pow(x,2) - 25 * pow(y,2) + 16)>=0.0 else (0 + 15 * x)/15
```

And this should produce the following result :

[image: result]

Comment: Nice workaround! Quick note though: `(0+15*x)/15` equals simply `x`, so would make the conditional simpler :)

Comment: Well, that looks about exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't know you could use conditionals in the equation. That opens so many possibilities! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Would it be possible to, instead of having the conditional be that the squared function is greater than 0, that x is less than or equal to 1 and greater than or equal to -1? `-1<=x<=1` I'm not sure if that would change the results, but it was how I initially set the function to work. Is that possible by saying `[function] if x >= -1 AND x <= 1 else [alt function]`? As it stands, I'm not sure why it's slanted like that. I thought it should be flat, perpendicular to the x-axis.

Comment: You can use conditionals such as that, but equally you can set the range in the X Size and Y Size fields in the tool panel on the left. Setting X Size to 2 would naturally make it range from -1 to 1. Perhaps one of the terms in the equation is incorrect?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a heart shape? If you remove the last bit you get "( sqrt(-16*fabs(x)+40 * sqrt(fabs(x)) * y - 16 * pow(x,2) - 25 * pow(y,2) + 16))/15 if (-16*fabs(x)+40 * sqrt(fabs(x)) * y - 16 * pow(x,2) - 25 * pow(y,2) + 16)>=0.0 else (0)" which does produce a heart shape on a flat plane.

Comment: That's what the issue was. Not sure how I messed that up, but thanks for figuring that out!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The problem that prevents your equation from working with the `Add Mesh: Extra Objects > Math Function > Z Math` , is that you're using a `sqrt` function which is undefined for negative values.

When the math function operator tries to evaluate different values for X and Y, it raises an exception the first time that evaluation fails due to an attempt to sqrt a negative value.

Another option is to write a script of your own to generate the mesh only where the equation provides valid results. I wrote a quick script to do that below. It's incomplete as it only calculates vertices coordinates (result in the image above), and does not generate edges and faces, but it's a start:

```
import bpy, bmesh
import numpy     as np
from   math      import sqrt
from   itertools import product

# Define X and Y values lower bound, upper bound and number of points
lb, ub, n = ( -30, 30, 1000 )

# Calculate all the possible X-Y combinations and convert to a numpy array
xy = np.array( list( product( np.linspace( lb, ub, n ), np.linspace( lb, ub, n ) ) ) )

# Split X and Y to different arrays and initialize Z array
xs = xy[:,0]
ys = xy[:,1]
zs = []

# Iterate over every x and y value, and try to calculate the z.
# Append result if successful, and nan if not
for x, y in zip( xs, ys ):
    try:
        zs.append(
            ( 
                sqrt( 
                    -16 * abs(x) + 40 * sqrt( abs(x) ) * y - 16 * pow( x, 2 ) - 25 * pow( y, 2 ) + 16 
                ) + 15 * x 
            ) / 15 
        )
    except:
        zs.append( np.nan )

# Drop nan values from all axes
mask = np.logical_not(np.isnan(zs))
xs = xs[ mask ]
ys = ys[ mask ]
zs = np.array( zs )[ mask ]

# Generate mesh
bm = bmesh.new()

# Add vertices
for x, y, z in zip( xs, ys, zs ):
    bm.verts.new( (x,y,z) )

m = bpy.data.meshes.new( "equation" )

bm.to_mesh( m )

o = bpy.data.objects.new( "equation", m )
bpy.context.scene.objects.link( o )
```

This script uses external, non built-in libraries (namely numpy). You can achieve the same result without numpy, but it makes some of the calculations quicker and easier.

Comment: Ah. I was hoping it would only generate for valid values and simply ignore invalids. Guess it's not the TI-89 I'm used to XD. I'm sadly not familiar with using straight up text in Blender, but I shall endeavor to try. Thanks for your answer, it is most helpful!